# how chage an image of a gameobject and display it on unity

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am pretty new at unity and I'm trying to make a card game.
I created 52 objects in a list and each object has set and get options.
now I'm trying to get an image of an object and display it on the game through the VS.
my problem is that I don't know how to change the image of the game object in the VisualStudio.

This is the code I did:

```
// The purpose of the function is to display the card image in canvas when play 
 public void Deal () {   
    deck = GenerateDeck();// generate a deck of 52 cards
    Card card = deck[15]; // refer to a spesific card in deck
    Sprite image = card.GetCardImage();
    imagecards.sprite = image;
    card1.AddComponent<Image>();
    card1.sprite=imagecards; <- this line dosent work
    GameObject playercard = Instantiate(card1, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    playercard.transform.SetParent(PlayerArea.transform, false);        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the now added Image Component via. `GetComponent<Image>()` to acces the sprite and change it.

**Example:**

```
card1.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = imagecards;
```

Comment: If it helped please mark it as the solution thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that when you click on the gray check mark left to the answer